# Why did I receive a 10 day suspension for what I believe is a perfectly valid comment with no ill-intent whatsoever?

Tags: discussion, comments, mod-abuse

I was suspended for 10 days beginning March 31st at just after 2pm. My 10-day suspension ended a few hours ago. The alleged basis for my suspension was that I made the following comment under [this recent question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/613847/digital-voltmeter-reading-half-the-voltage-measured-with-fluke-multimeter): -

> *To the OP: before you purchased the so-called voltmeter, did you read
> the data sheet to see what the input impedance is? Would you buy
> curtains because of the colour or because they are the right size?*

**The mods also said this: -**

- Your recent interactions cross a line and need to stop because they affect others negatively.
- "*Others did see it as condescending and flagged it*" from a comment under the question by Sam Gibson (a moderator).

**Therefore, my question is this: -**

Why was I suspended for ten days for making this comment?

**And, my point is this: -**

If I make a genuinely honest comment that is seen by "others" to be condescending then, why should I be suspended because "others" chose to read "badness" into what I wrote. I'm the only person who has a window into my brain and, I'm the only person who can say whether I was being condescending/snide or, trying to be helpful.

**Let me state this: I was trying to be helpful.**

So, on the say-so of some nameless people who incorrectly judged my intent, why should that result in any punishment at all?

**Other information:**

I appealed the suspension via the normal route and was told this: -

> *At your request, an employee has been assigned to review the case. If
> they find any evidence of malicious behaviour, they will take
> appropriate action to correct the problem. However, we are not able to
> provide details of that review nor will you receive further responses
> about this issue.*

So, it's not much of an appeal-system if you don't get any further feedback hence, why I have posted this question on meta.

I want feedback and I deserve feedback. I did not deserve to be suspended for any length of time.

Image of PM from mods should it be of any interest: -

[image]

Comment: You often fall into giving condescending comments but I hadn't seen this one before. I am guilty of doing the same thing. I think it is because we get so frustrated at questions that show a serious lack of critical thinking or significant effort on the part of the OP. It's possible that relaxing educational standards during COVID lead to a generation of learners who expect to be spoon fed everything. Try being an instructor... reddit.com/r/professors is full of these stories.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson it's not condescending - if an EE newbie buys stuff from eBay believing that what is shown in the advert is all they need to know then, they need a healthy reminder that buying anything that is important needs research (whether it's a module or some curtains or shoes or whatever). I am reminding them that EE stuff is just as likely to be inappropriate for their needs when bought from eBay as curtains or shoes. It's important that what you buy is "well defined" and, you consider your purchases carefully. I was being helpful; I was trying to save them money on their next shop.

Comment: OK it was amazon where the guy bought the stuff from but, it's the same principle; do your research and save time and money in the long run. I even added a further link to a Q and A that explained this a little later. [Link to Q and A](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/504044/what-to-check-for-when-buying-an-electronic-component-or-module). I also note that this extra comment has received no upvotes (several comments have) and this to me means that newbies or hobbyists just do not understand what I'm trying to explain to them. Hence possibly why someone thought it condescending.

Comment: I am not sure if professional teaching was/is part of your job. For me, it isn't. But I regularly work with students and the more experienced I get, the more I feel that I can't communicate with newbies properly. I understand the frustration, but I know that metaphorized snappy comment are a step in the wrong direction, and patience is needed. If you don't feel like giving patient advice, it is maybe good to take a breath and move on. At worst impatient comments sound mocking. At best, they are rather useless to the OP, even if they are upvoted by experienced site members

Comment: @tobalt here's an **escalation of stupidity**: if my comment is seen as rude/problematic by a specific younger generation of people then, it's certainly not seen as rude/problematic to an older generation of people. So, why should I be punished for talking as I do and, if I am to be punished for that then, it only seems fair that the specific younger generation should be punished for taking offence and not recognizing common-sense. To avoid that **escalation of stupidity**, what should happen is that I am not punished for my comment. **I was trying to save the OP money on their next shop.**

Comment: @Andyaka - Your use of inflammatory bold text (which could be trying to imply that mods are/have been stupid) means that I won't be replying to this, as there is no sign that further replies will be constructive. You are, of course, entitled to your views. However if someone breaks the [Code of Conduct](/help/conduct) (whether they agree with it or not) then the consequences are explained near the bottom of that page. I had planned a different update, but I'm not going to be harassed. You can [contact SE staff](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/contact) if you want to discuss further.

Comment: @SamGibson I was explaining a hypothetical situation to tobalt and, actually, to me, it looks like you are trying to find an excuse not to provide the details I requested. In fact I am saying that an escalation of stupidity is just that (and is to be avoided). Please read it again in context and please, provide me with what I request.

Comment: @Andyaka - "*it looks like you are trying to find an excuse not to provide the details I requested*" That's your opinion. My answer clearly said that I would ask for your agreement to publicly share both the comments and previous message history (the latter you refused) and *contact Stack Exchange staff* for the next steps. I did not agree to provide anything to you - I was just trying to help gather what I thought SE would ask for. As I just explained, I now see that there is nothing constructive here for me to help with. You can (and always have been) able to contact SE staff via that link.

Comment: I contacted them the day I was suspended and received an email and responded to that email but, as I said in my question (above), they replied this: *However, we are not able to provide details of that review nor will you receive further responses about this issue.* - and that is practically useless to me because it doesn't do what it says on the tin i.e. "an appeal against suspension" - it's meaningless and a whitewash. It has the potential to look like a cover-up.

Comment: @Andyaka your request to do a line-by-line review of your flags is not reasonable nor is something that we will consider. A CM has reviewed your suspension and found it to be warranted. Furthermore, you can see by the signature that it came from the Community Team. Your recently deleted answer from 03/30 is another good example of behavior that "cross a line and need to stop because they affect others negatively". Regardless of intention, we need to moderate based on the negative impact your interactions are having, so we recommend that you review the CoC, our guidance, and adjust accordingly.

Comment: @Bella_Blue I'm unsure what deleted answer (3/30) you refer to. How would I find that answer in order to check what I did wrong? Is there a link to it @bella_blue? I will also say that what I requested is perfectly reasonable in a democratic situation. However, if all you can provide is what was offered originally by Sam Gibson then that will have to do AND, I don't mind it being public. The perception of people here is that SE staff are unanswerable for their actions to the common user/answerer and, that can never been seen as a good thing in the wider context of the site.

Comment: @Bella_Blue Regarding "signature" what does this mean i.e. "what signature" do you refer to?

Comment: @Andyaka - "*offered originally by Sam Gibson*" That misleads people: *nothing was offered by me*. Please read my answer again. I asked for your permission to publicly share two sets of information (one of which you refused) since I expected that *if* your question was going to get a full answer, both sets of information would need to be public. Then, as I explained in my answer & a few hours ago in a comment, I said "*one of us can contact Stack Exchange staff to confirm that they are also OK with us posting your private flags and communication history here*". I did not offer more than that.

Comment: “Justice must not only be done, but must also be seen to be done”. I think that this 
 applies here and if not, then stack exchange needs to rethink how it presents itself.

Comment: @Andyaka "my comment is ... certainly not seen as rude/problematic to an older generation of people" I'm in my 60s and I'd like to disassociate myself from the idea that I don't find this comment condescending. Both the curtain analogy and preceding voltmeter with "so-called" seem unhelpful.

Comment: @GrahamNye are you quite content to buy electronic modules from eBay or Amazon with no data sheet?

Comment: @Andyaka I don't disagree with the technical content of your posts; indeed I often find them instructive myself. But the comments from a number of people above suggest that you could be more tactful when phrasing your advice especially, it seems to me, when answering questions from less experienced posters.

Comment: @GrahamNye do you think that EE modules advertised on ebay/amazon should not be referred to as "so-called"? Is that what you are saying? Do you think that ebay/amazon (who don't normally provide data sheets and have very limited proof of authenticity or quality of their products) are a sensible choice for **anyone** involved in electronics? Let me lay my cards on the table; I think that ebay and amazon are a very non-cost-effective choice for EE modules. That is why I used the term "so-called". What other meaning could I have for using it? I've never hidden from saying this BTW.

Comment: @Andyaka Describing a voltmeter as "so-called" suggests it isn't actually a voltmeter. The reviews for the voltmeter in the original question suggest that it does work. It's basic but cheap so is cost-effective. Sometimes you just need a basic meter. I have a 2½ digit voltmeter in my car to keep an eye on the battery during lockdown. It's fine for that job. Also in context "so-called" is another layer of condescension.

Comment: If you choose to read it that way then I cannot stop you but, clearly to me, the more obvious reading of the phrase relates to how ebay and amazon are just not to be regarded as (a) cost-effective suppliers of EE modules due to their lack of data sheets, (b) having unclear quality control and (c) having very little in the way of traceability.

Comment: @Andyaka in the last year or so I have come across dozens of your comments that struck me as hostile, dismissive or gratuitously mean in tone, as if you were personally angry at the OP. I'm sure you don't perceive yourself that way, but I do think you have an issue with how you communicate online.

Comment: @DamienD the point in question here is the comment I made that was reported in the suspension notice above. But, please do link to one of them.

Comment: The worst were quickly deleted by mods but here's a few examples: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/608119/why-does-the-can-bus-need-termination-resistors-and-other-buses-dont#comment1601107_608119

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/607735/how-does-high-voltage-increase-power-without-changing-current#comment1600012_607735

Comment: Among other things, you keep pointing out mistakes by asking rhetorical questions where the only possible answer is "because I'm stupid".

Comment: I see absolutely nothing wrong with those comments. But then I'm bound to say that aren't I? I also see nothing wrong with rhetorical questions either and, if you choose to extend that to mean that the answer leads to someone regarding themselves as stupid then that is your connection. I think you are on shaky ground here. Have you never been stupid; I have - plenty of times and, when someone points out my stupidity (even if they do it harshly) then I thank them because, they have removed another bit of stupidity from my head. In other words, they have done me a favour. That's my philosophy.

Comment: And, what was the price I paid to be corrected; a moment of embarrassment and feeling stupid, possibly anger with myself for being daft. These are small prices to pay for the pain of learning leading to truth and accuracy. You don't have to like my philosophy of course.

Comment: @Andyaka You asked why you were suspended for making a particular comment. A moderator has provided an answer explaining that multiple comments flagged by multiple people were regarded as problematic. But instead of considering why multiple people find your posts can be rude you are continuing to put forward technical arguments to me trying to justify your original comment. You claimed "I was trying to be helpful" but you also wrote in a comment (14th 17:09) "it only seems fair that the ... younger generation should be punished...".   1/2

Comment: @Andyaka What sort of an attitude is that to approach questions with? It's hardly surprising that people can find your posts rude if that's your underlying thought process. Surely you should be writing answers on a Q&A site because you want to help the questioners, not punish them? 2/2

Comment: @GrahamNye exactly what do you mean when you say this: *What sort of an attitude is that to approach questions with?* - what has this got to do with how I answer questions?

Comment: It appears that one of my replies to Graham Nye has been removed, possibly by mods. If so, can you explain why? Or maybe I just imagined I'd answered?

Comment: @Andyaka How do you expect to write polite, constructive answers if your underlying attitude is looking for ways to "punish" the "younger generation"? Rather than learning from your suspension and looking for ways to make less abrasive posts you seem determined to defend your existing posting style. If you carry on without making changes you'll presumably face further suspension and an eventual ban. It would be a shame to lose your technical expertise so I hope you are able to post in line with the CoC.

Comment: @GrahamNye just so you are aware, I've flagged your last 3 comments for moderator intervention.

Comment: @Andyaka FTR I don't recall flagging any posts and certainly not the one that is the subject of this thread. I didn't see the comment that was allegedly removed.

Comment: @Andyaka - We saw that you had flagged comments, but here is the problem: (a) You asked a question where behaviour is clearly going to be "on topic". (b) You have given your justification for your behaviour. (c) But when someone criticises that behaviour (or the stated justification for it) you have flagged their comments. That doesn't seem fair & equitable - deleting those critical comments would prevent other site members from reading a counterpoint to your statements. || Currently, those flags have been denied. I am seeking further advice from other people on this.

Comment: @Andyaka - Re: "*It appears that one of my replies to Graham Nye has been removed, possibly by mods*" None of your comments have (so far) been removed by mods. The only one of your comments which has been deleted is a much earlier one, which you deleted yourself (and then replaced with a modified version).

Comment: @SamGibson Graham Nye is misrepresenting what I have said in the comment earlier on in reply to Tobalt. That misrepresentation is rude and, because he has continued to do it, it becomes harrassment.

Comment: @Andyaka "he has continued to do it" I've continued to discuss the point because you asked me for an explanation (your 18th 16:41Z). Asking for an explanation then complaining when you got one is, as Sam noted in a different context, unfair. I had said my bit yesterday; I'm only posting now because of your comment to Sam.

Comment: @Andyaka  "misrepresenting" I've followed the normal expectations for quoting; omissions were indicated by ellipses (...) and I provided the date and time of the original comment to make it easier for anyone to see the full wording (though it's only a scroll away). I quoted the parts relevant to my point which is that I'm unable to see any context in which a SE user (i.e. not a moderator/admin) should be talking about "punishing" other users - any context, so the specific context is irrelevant. 
1/2

Comment: @Andyaka If I've misunderstood your comment perhaps you could rephrase it to make the intended meaning clearer.In the same comment you've also taken it upon yourself to claim that your approach is acceptable to "an older generation". As someone who would usually be seen as a member of that generation (hey! I'm 60+ years young) you certainly do not speak for me. 2/2

Comment: @Andyaka "harrassment" (sic) Making unjustified complaints to the moderators could be seen as harassment. However I'm not going to make a formal complaint about that. I'm sure Sam and his colleagues have got better things to do.

Comment: @GrahamNye you are misrepresenting my comment that talks about an escalation of stupidity and reading it as if I thought it was something that should happen. I clearly say at the bottom of that comment that it should be avoided. Stick to the facts of the question is my advice dude.

Comment: @Andyaka "Stick to the facts" Towards the end of your comment you wrote "what should happen is that I am not punished for my comment." So it seems you are suggesting it should be avoided *in your case* which is a somewhat different point.

Comment: None of the comments I've seen warrant any sort of suspension, IMO. I believe the best teachers are the ones that get you to examine your own blind spots or preconceptions. Sometimes this is done through rhetorical questions or ones that might seem a little patronizing, but can be quite effective. Since I cannot see the full history of flagged comments and complaints, I cannot decide whether the action was justified. There is a difference between pointing out someone's error in light jest and _actual_ abuse. But I increasingly feel that modern culture is unable to make that distinction.

Comment: Aha a breath of fresh air - someone who possibly sees my point of view @JYelton - it also seems that not being able to digest the full story of a comment or, recognize the true motive behind a comment is sadly lacking in modern culture. I mean I was also accused (by someone who made a link to one of my comments) of being "*hostile, dismissive or gratuitously mean in tone, as if you were personally angry at the OP*" yet, the comment I made was clearly supported by a moderator directly below.

Comment: ... And in the other link I was thanked by the OP who said this: *thanks for that educational, useful comment*. Maybe that should have been regarded as sarcasm but, at the time, I accepted it at face value. Maybe I should flag it in retrospect (not). I'm not saying I am perfect but I am saying that my suspension and the way it was delivered was NOT justice being seen to be done.

Comment: @All - I have let these comments run for a while and people have had an opportunity to state their views. There has been advice provided by Stack Exchange staff here (and by me in my answer). However I have decided that things are not heading towards a resolution - the same points are being repeated and there are increasing signs of frustration. With the difficulties moderating this topic fairly as well, it is now time to close comments to prevent further problems.

Comment: (continued) The [Code of Conduct](/help/conduct) is what it is, even if someone disagrees with it. Stack Exchange require us **all** to comply with it and they task mods with applying *those* rules. The sanctions for failing to comply with the CoC are listed at the bottom of that linked page & they will continue to be applied, with the best judgement that we can use.

Comment: Note for future readers: One of the [sets of comments](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/608119/why-does-the-can-bus-need-termination-resistors-and-other-buses-dont#comment1601107_608119) linked & discussed above, has been removed. It was [not a good example of what we want to show as complying with the Code of Conduct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311737/lets-hold-language-in-comments-to-the-same-standard-as-posts). (When written, that post's author was SE staff.) In any case, comments should be [considered as (potentially) only temporary](/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 2):

Since I'm currently online, I'll give a partial reply. At this stage, I'm deliberately not responding fully to your questions, for the reasons I explain below.

> Why was I suspended for ten days for making this comment?

You weren't suspended lightly and you weren't suspended for only that comment, but I see that the suspension message only mentioned that one and perhaps this has caused some misunderstanding.

Actually that comment you wrote was just "the final straw" and it was the ongoing flags received on several of your comments, from different site members over recent weeks, and the events even before that, which led to that suspension with that duration.

> So, on the say-so of some nameless people who incorrectly judged my intent, why should that result in any punishment at all?

Your *intent* is irrelevant since, as you said in another point, that cannot be known by others, with certainty. In general terms (and not referring to you) unfortunately some people lie, including about their intent when writing. Therefore relying only on what anyone says about their intent, would be untenable for moderation purposes on any internet site.

Instead we respond to how someone's words and language (which they chose and they have to take responsibility for) come across to other people, primarily through flags. This is why the [Code of Conduct](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/conduct) says, among several other points:

> #### **Unacceptable Behavior**
>
> **No subtle put-downs or unfriendly language.**
> Even if you don’t intend it, this can have a negative impact on others.

It is the *language chosen* and how things come across to (and affect) other people, which is acted upon by moderators and SE staff - not the intent behind the writing, as we cannot judge that. *Multiple people* assessed that certain comments you made over recent weeks, continued to come across as being put-downs / unfriendly / patronising / condescending etc. when they flagged them.

It's the same when *you* flag someone else's comments. Your flags indicate that *their* words and language have come across to *you* in a way that breaks the Code of Conduct, even though you cannot know *their* intent.

In the part of your comment which you quoted, you said:

> Would you buy curtains because of the colour or because they are the right size?

Considering the original question was about the behaviour of a voltmeter, that comparison with buying curtains came across, to multiple people, as unfriendly i.e. a condescending mocking of the OP.

---

For the reason below I cannot say more publicly at the moment, even though it would help to better explain the lead-up to this current situation and therefore to explain the context to your questions.

If you *really* want us to copy into the public domain here, each of the flags leading up to that suspension and relevant previous history & communications with you (*without* mentioning other site member's names e.g. who raised flags) in order to give context and explain why it was a 10-day suspension as you asked above, then please say so.

Then we can discuss between the moderators how to handle this (I've never seen someone want to discuss a suspension in public before) and one of us can contact Stack Exchange staff to confirm that they are also OK with us posting your private flags and communication history here. (Normally, we wouldn't disclose this sort of information publicly, of course.)

As a genuine concern: Once the (normally private) information is put here and indexed by search engines etc., then I believe it would be very difficult for you to fully remove it from the internet, if you decided later that you wanted to do that.

Comment: Yes please, I want to see each of the comments in public that I made that raised flags.

Comment: Whether it's public or not, I never really understood why stackexchange never provides detailed info regarding the offending comments to the suspended users. How can you improve your behavior if you aren't even told what's wrong? I guess it's to avoid creating drama, but now, there's more drama because users get suspended without realizing they crossed the line multiple times. Users don't know how far or close they are to a suspension before it happens. I've never been suspended, but maybe I'm one rough comment away from it... Who knows?

Comment: @dim absolutely correct. Without feedback how can anyone know until it's too late and then it's proper drama. This cloak of secrecy has to stop. It's like going to court and being convicted of a series of multiple offences (witnessed by people who shall remain anonymous) where only the most recent "offence" is available. In my case, the reading of my latest comment by unnamed people is at fault - I thoroughly question their judgement. It's almost pythonesque in its ridiculousness.

Comment: @dim - Hi, "*stackexchange never provides detailed info regarding the offending comments to the suspended users*" That's an incorrect statement about the lack of feedback. Before there's any suspension, there has been *lots* of feedback (with the exception of instant suspension for bigotry etc.). "*users get suspended without realizing they crossed the line multiple times* Not true, as the message history with a suspended user will show. After warnings have not improved things, suspensions follow. || However more info in *this* suspension message would have helped, but you are missing context.

Comment: @Andyaka - Thanks for confirming about putting your previous comments here. However you did not reply about the second part, of including "relevant previous history & communications with you". So please give permission for that to be made public too, as other users like *dim* are missing the context from previous private communications, leading to an incomplete picture. Thanks.

Comment: Ok. As I said, I never experienced this, so I wouldn't know. But I remember seeing quite a few users suprised to become suddenly suspended (in the past, and possibly on other sites), but maybe the full picture is never quite clear to us people not directly involved in the matter.

Comment: @dim If a user does something egregious like directly insulting another user, they may get suspended without warning, but in most cases users receive one or more warnings before a suspension, which can thus rarely be considered surprising.

Comment: @SamGibson you said this: *If you really want us to copy into the public domain here, each of the flags leading up to that suspension* - and I'm happy to see all the evidence that relates directly to this latest suspension. Regarding my previous suspensions (three?), they are irrelevant to this current suspension so, avoiding clouding the issue in question, it would make more sense not to include them. It's this suspension I'm appealing against in this question.

Comment: @Andyaka - You truncated what I said. Then you said: "*Regarding my previous suspensions (three?), they are irrelevant to this current suspension*" No, they are not irrelevant. Previous communications (including, but not limited to, warnings before those suspensions) give necessary context & background to answer your question. The reason this suspension was *this* duration & was handled in a different way, was *directly because* of what has happened previously. As I said, *dim* (for example) has incomplete context as they have not seen all the previous warnings leading up to this suspension.

Comment: @SamGibson what led to my suspension (this time) was a series of flags raised against me yes? What led to the length of my suspension was my "previous convictions". I am objecting to this suspension (not the length of it) and I'd like to know what were my comments (that were flagged) that led to this unsatisfactory situation.

Comment: @Andyaka - "*what led to my suspension (this time) was a series of flags raised against me yes?*" Not exactly - it was a series of flags *in the context of previous warnings*. A user who hadn't received previous warnings, would (if it was up to me) have received a warning, rather than being suspended. Context and history is everything to your question of why you were suspended, rather than warned. "*I am objecting to this suspension (not the length of it)*" That's not clear from your question, which asks "*Why was I suspended **for ten days** for making this comment?*" (my bold).

Comment: (continued) Anyway, since you haven't agreed to (what I believe) is giving necessary context from previous events in order to answer your question, I have escalated this to Stack Exchange staff for advice about what I am allowed to say / disclose. I plan to update things here after they reply.

Comment: You should also be prepared to show the flags that were raised against me that were declined by you (not anyone else).

Comment: @Andyaka - "*You should also be prepared to show the flags that were raised against me that were declined by you (not anyone else).*" Since you are picking only on me, this feels like an attempt to harass me. I will escalate this to Stack Exchange for advice.

Comment: OK that was a little crass of me. I meant the "mods in general" over this recent period. I was also trying to suggest that if there were many more flags declined on comments I had made (than those upheld) then it puts the mods (you) in better light. That was the real meaning why I said that comment.

Comment: Possibly it would be useful if users could notice if their own posts were flagged. That way, one could get immediate feedback like "maybe I crossed a line here" regardless of whether it leads to a mod action. And one could adapt oneself better.

Comment: @tobalt I think that's a good idea. A notification of a flag against you works for me but, I still want to get to the bottom of why I was suspended.

Comment: @tobalt - Hi, FYI I have spent some time researching this, and found 3 Meta.SE posts with relevant previous discussions [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/327110), [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/318497) & [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/368802). As far as I can see, there are reasons for *not* doing this and I see no plans to introduce that feature. You can raise it again on Meta.SE, if you want, but I don't expect a different conclusion. || Except in extreme cases, before a first CoC suspension, a site member will be warned with examples of what has broken the CoC.

Comment: (continued)  If they want more details or to learn more, they should reply constructively to that message since site members can only reply once per message from mods. However not everyone replies constructively, and some members squander their one reply by sending us anger and abuse after their warning. In those cases, we typically don't reply further - it would be pointless anyway, if they didn't want to learn how to change their behaviour to comply with the CoC. Some relevant advice in [this Meta.SE question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/311737).

Comment: Thanks @SamGibson I read some comments there and understand the issues with such a feature.

Comment: I think that your prevention of comments under my question is yet another case of justice not being seen to be done and is biased against resolving this issue despite you saying the contrary. The comments you removed from a linked question are also a highly suspicious looking move by you to degrade what I was trying to say. You may be a mod but your behaviour certainly does not look to be reasonable here.

Comment: @Andyaka - I have done what I believe is appropriate (with advice from others) to keep things calm and provide appropriate advice. You have had plenty of opportunity to say what you wanted to say. After almost 50 comments under your question, someone had to make a decision about the value of carrying on - so I did. You are welcome to escalate to SE staff who, as you know, are already involved. That is your escalation path for what you claim is my unreasonable behaviour. I will be happy to follow whatever recommendations SE staff make. Do not try to harass me further here, you have had your say